# How do you match the rotation of an object based on the edges of another object?

Tags: modeling

[image]

How do you match the pentagon's edges with the edges circled in blue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use snapping, but I would use vertex snapping, instead of edges: enable snapping, choose vertex, then in edit mode start the rotation (on the correct axis).

While rotating, move your cursor over a vertex of the reference shape, to get the alignment. Sometimes, depending on your exact setup, and the various object transforms, it could work also in object mode.

Here is a simplified example:

[image]